# Hadoop HDFS - Cannot give +x permission to files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, fuse, cloudera

So, I used Cloudera's installation and management tool to get a 3 node cluster of servers up and running.

I have HDFS running and can see / create directories etc.

I went ahead and installed the Fuse plugin which allows me to mount the HDFS as a file system. Everything works fine. I can write files to the folders etc.

Problem:

when I run `'chmod 777 ./file.sh'` in the mounted drive, it doesnt give any errors but when i do a `'ls -l'` it only has:

```
'-rw-rw-rw- 1 root nobody 26 Oct  5 08:57 run.sh'
```

When I run `'sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod 777 /run.sh'` it still has the same permissions. No matter what I do in any way I cannot get execute permission on any files.

I have disabled permissions in Cloudera manager, and also chown'd the folder (chmod -R 777 the folder also). But nothing seems to be working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like adding: "umask=000" to the fstab mount line did the trick. (also added exec for good measure)

Thanks!